# Get samples within a namespace from a perf record

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I have generated a perf.data with the command:

```
perf record -F 99 -g -p <pid>
```

So far so good -- I can run perf report, and generate flamegraphs.

Now, I'd like to get a count how many callstack samples contain at least one occurence of a particular namespace (eg unique_namespace::).  Anyone know how I could do something like this?

Comment: There is -D option of record to raw dump all events recorded in perf.data as text, they may have grepable symbol names. There is --sort option in perf report to group on various columns (dso, pid, srcline, srcfile), but there is no support of grouping by namespace.

Comment: hmm thank you, I'll look into that.

Comment: Sorry,  -D option of `perf report`, not record